# How to fill the values of a dataframe for few columns from a list?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a list of lists,

```
labels = [['A','B','D','E'], ['G','J','H'],['C','H']]
```

I have a data frame

```
          A    B    C    D    E    G    H    J
         NAN  NAN  NAN  NAN  NAN  NAN  NAN  NAN
  Df =   NAN  NAN  NAN  NAN  NAN  NAN  NAN  NAN
         NAN  NAN  NAN  NAN  NAN  NAN  NAN  NAN
```

I want to take one list at a time and check its value against the column names in Df and fill its cell with value 1 if the column name matches the string in the list else fill 0.

Expected output:

```
          A    B    C    D    E    G    H    J
          1    1    0    1    1    0    0    0 
  Df =    0    0    0    0    0    1    1    1
          0    0    1    0    0    0    1    0
```

If first list is selected it has to fill the first row of the Df based on the above condition. Similarly second list should fill the second row of the Df.

Comment: It looks like you've spent some time understanding the data, but no time coming up with a solution - can you share what you think the solution might be like, or some code of what you already tried? SO isn't there to ask people to write your code, but to help you solve problems you may have with code you wrote, or don't understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a crude method:

```
for row, col in enumerate(labels):
    df.loc[row,col] = 1
print(df.fillna(0).astype(int))
```

Output:

```
   A  B  C  D  E  G  H  J
0  1  1  0  1  1  0  0  0
1  0  0  0  0  0  1  1  1
2  0  0  1  0  0  0  1  0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use list comprehension for this and iterate over the labels

```
[df.set_value(i,x,1)  for i,x in enumerate(labels)]    
df.fillna(0).astype('int8')
```

Output

```
    A   B   C   D   E   G   H   J
0   1   1   0   1   1   0   0   0
1   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   1
2   0   0   1   0   0   0   1   0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

labels = [['A','B','D','E'], ['G','J','H'],['C','H']]
unique = set(x for l in labels for x in l)

data = []
for item in labels:
    raw = {}
    for value in unique:
        if value in item:
            raw[value] = 1
        else:
            raw[value] = 0
    data.append(raw)

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
df = df.reindex(sorted(df.columns), axis=1)
```

Output:

```
   A  B  C  D  E  G  H  J
0  1  1  0  1  1  0  0  0
1  0  0  0  0  0  1  1  1
2  0  0  1  0  0  0  1  0
```